# Displaying image from a folder

Tags: php

image displays in the browser whrn the following code is used.But when the code is used inside html,the image does not appear instead a small box appear.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('http://localhost/picture013.jpg');
?>
```

for example when i use no image is displayed.

```
 <html>
<body>
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile('http://localhost/picture013.jpg');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

in short i wanted to display all the images from a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this one

```
<?php
    $dir  = "localhost/image"; // your folder name ex: image
    $imgs = glob($dir ."/*.jpg"); // get your image files with .jpg 

    foreach ($imgs AS $i) {
      echo "<img src='$i'>"; // 
    }
?>
```

Comment: html>

<?php
$dir  = "http://localhost/upload"; // your folder name ex: image
$imgs = glob($dir ."*.jpg"); // get your image files with .jpg 

foreach ($imgs AS $i) {
  echo "<img src='$dir / $i'>"; // 
}

?>
</html>

Comment: dont know why but why after using following code nothing is happening<?php


$folder = "localhost/upload";
$images = glob($folder."/*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image){ 
    echo '1';
    
}

?>

Comment: Are you sure that your `upload` folder is in `localhost` directory? not in your website folder ?

Comment: yeah i know you are working on xampp, but do you put your folder like this `C:\xampp\htdocs\yourwebfolder\upload` ?

Comment: if its true then just change ` $folder = "localhost/upload"; ` to this one ` $folder = "upload"; ` and everything gonna be alright :)

Answer (score 0):

Think about what this is doing for a moment. That file already exists, you're not inventing image data from nothing, so why are you not just creating an element and link to that image?

Put an `<img src="some/location/picture013.jsp">` on the page with an echo/print instead, and whatever page needs to show that image will work just fine. In this case it's already a legal URL, so you can just add `<img src="http://localhost/picture013.jpg">` to whatever page needs it.

If it wasn't, you could make the server simply resolve the location you're pointing to with an .htaccess rule, or simply have the file live in an already web-visible directory. There is no reason to make PHP proxy the image data when it's already a normal web-visible resource; in fact, you're just over-complicating your code with unnecessary steps.

Comment: i am uploading images to a speciefic folder say upload and i want to display them.so i am using the following code :<html><body><div><?php $img='location of the folder';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('$img');
?></div></body></html>

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you know they're files on your server, and you can simply have them in a web-visible location so you can use PHP to generate the links with `<?php echo "<img src='".$imgfile."'>"; ?>`